# VHDL file reading program shows an error

Tags: file, file-io, vhdl

I was writing a vhdl code to read the image file. I converted the image file into a note pad file having 65536 lines.ie,256 X 256 pixels. Now when I am running the code I am getting a error that says:

```
Fatal error in ForLoop loop at C:/MentorGraphics/modeltech_6.5c/win32/test.vhd line 39
# HDL call sequence:
# Stopped at C:/MentorGraphics/modeltech_6.5c/win32/test.vhd 39 ForLoop loop
```

why it is happening like that.. I am attaching the code below:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use std.textio.all;

entity IMAGE_READ is
Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
IMAGE_LOAD : IN  STD_LOGIC:='1';
IMAGE_DONE : OUT  STD_LOGIC);
end entity;

architecture Behavioral of IMAGE_READ is
type image is array (1 to 256,1 to 256) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
file IMAGE_FILE:text open read_mode is "D:\Documents\ORIGINAL IMAGE.txt";

begin
PROCESS(CLK,ROW,COLUMN,IMAGE_LOAD)
variable LINE_NUMBER:line;
variable TEMP_PIXEL_VALUE: bit_vector(7 downto 0);
variable image_matrix:IMAGE;

BEGIN
if (clk'event and clk = '1') then 

IF(IMAGE_LOAD='1') THEN
for i in 1 to 256 loop
for j in 1 to 256 loop
    readline (IMAGE_FILE, LINE_NUMBER);           
    read (LINE_NUMBER, TEMP_PIXEL_VALUE);                 
    image_matrix(i,j) := to_stdlogicvector(TEMP_PIXEL_VALUE);
        if(i=256 and j=256) then
            TEMP_image_done:='1';
            image_done<='1';
        else
            TEMP_image_done:='0';
            image_done<='0';
        end if;
END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END IF;

END IF;
END PROCESS;

end Behavioral;
```

How to correct it?

Comment: What does the file look like? By the way, I'm assuming by "a note pad file" you mean a simple text file, right? Lol.

Comment: yes it is a text file

Comment: How big is the file?  How many times do you try to read from it?  You never check for EndFile, you could easily be reading the file many times and reading past the end of file.

Comment: It is important to know did the error occur on the first read of the file or after many reads.  To help you figure this out, use breakpoints on your code.  It would help if we knew which line number 39 is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to debug the program; preferably in simulation.
Look for clues as to the error : for example, what are the values of the loop counters i and j when the error occurs?

What is the current line of the file?
What is the previous line?
What value do you get for Temp_Pixel from the faulty line?

and so on.

Eventually you will see something unexpected and that will lead you to the answer.

Comment: got it..the count shold be 128